# django-paypal deprecation error : Use of the initial['return_url'] is Deprecated

Tags: django-paypal

I am trying to integrate django-paypal payment in my app but I keep getting this error even though I am using the latest version.

```
Please use initial['return'] instead""", DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: The use of the initial['return_url'] is Deprecated.
Please use initial['return'] instead
```

This happens after the call to  `PayPalPaymentsForm`

```
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
```

Is there any fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do what it says, change that `return_url` to just `return`.

You can reveal that from [the related code](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/forms.py):

```
def _fix_deprecated_return_url(self, initial_args):
    if 'return_url' in initial_args:
        warn("""The use of the initial['return_url'] is Deprecated.
                Please use initial['return'] instead""", DeprecationWarning)
        initial_args['return'] = initial_args['return_url']
        del initial_args['return_url']
    return initial_args
```